# Change the location of .bashrc

Tags: bash, bashrc

Is it possible to change the location of `.bashrc` from `/home/orhanc/.bashrc` to some other directory?

Comment: You can change /etc/.bashrc so that it will include the .bashrc in the special location (also different based on the users login/home directory).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes. You have three main options:

Symlink ~/.bashrc,

```
mv ~/.bashrc ~/blah && ln -s ~/blah/.bashrc ~/.bashrc
```

source the new file from ~/.bashrc,

```
mv ~/.bashrc ~/blah && cat > ~/.bashrc << 'EOF'
. ~/blah/.bashrc
EOF
```

or launch bash with `--rcfile`.

```
mv ~/.bashrc ~/blah
bash --rcfile ~/blah/.bashrc
```

Comment: Oh of course! If your couldn't tell, I'm still learning the ins and outs of using Linux and forgot about symlinks. Thank you!