# Changing the location of .bashrc in MINGW64 / git bash?

Tags: windows, bashrc, mingw

So here is how I am attempting to move the location of my bashrc file which is shoehorned into Windows!  Yay!

```
someuser@somehost MINGW64 ~
$ mv ~/.bashrc ~/OneDrive

someuser@somehost MINGW64 ~
$ ln -s ~/OneDrive/ ~/.bashrc
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/c/Users/ajleer/.bashrc': Device or resource busy
```

Per this question: [Change the location of .bashrc](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/98084/change-the-location-of-bashrc)

Is there some other way I can do this?  I don't know if I can pass `--rcfile` into git bash when it starts...unfortunately I end up with a directory?

```
$ ls -l ./.bashrc
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 1 ajleer 1049089 0 Jul 23 19:10 'OneDrive'
```

Comment: Does it work if you move the file, exit the shell, start a new shell (without any `.bashrc`) and _then_ do the `ln -s`?

Comment: I think you moved the file into directory `~/OneDrive` and then symlinked the directory instead of `ln -s ~/OneDrive/.bashrc ~/.bashrc`?